# How to set PostgreSQL's permission when migrate other database to it on AWS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-aurora, amazon-dms

We want to migrate an Oracle DB to a PostgreSQL DB in RDS with DMS.

There is an official guide for preparision in the PostgreSQL's DB:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-oracle2postgresql.steps.configurepostgresql.html

When I do with postgres user - 1

```
ALTER USER postgresql_dms_user WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Got

```
postgres=> ALTER USER postgresql_dms_user WITH SUPERUSER;
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
```

When I do a grant to sct user, got - 2

```
postgres=> GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA main TO postgresql_sct_user;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IN"
Line 1: GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA main TO postgresql_sct_user...
```

---

About 1, AWS' Aurora PostgreSQL' postgres user isn't the superuser

```
Role name | Group
postgres  | {rds_superuser}
```

Then how to grant a superuser to a new user?

About 2, I'm using PostgreSQL 12 version in the RDS, does the syntax not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link, with my emphasis:

> Create the AWS DMS user to connect to your target database, and grant Superuser or the necessary individual privileges **(or use the master username for RDS)**

Since you are using RDS, you should do what they say to do for RDS.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have changed to `rds_superuser`. Do you know the second syntax issue? May it should be `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA main GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO postgresql_sct_user;`

Comment: I think It should be `GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA...`.  It looks like one ALL got omitted from AWS doc.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You are right.